When should you commemorate a yahrtzeit for someone who was kidnapped then killed (at an unknown date)?
When the IDF retrieved the bodies of 6 Israeli hostages from Gaza, I wondered when should the families commemorate the yahrtzeit?
Should they commemorate when the bodies were retrieved or take an estimated guess as to when they were killed?
